# How to use epoch time of nanoseconds in Java?

Tags: java, integer, epoch

I have to send a message with current time(EPOCH) of the system and which will be sending according to following details. Also EPOCH time send in nanoseconds.

```
field - current_time
type - UINT64
byte size - 8
value - 0 to 1.84467E+19
```

My message structure is as below,

```
class MsgHeader {
   int message_length;
   String sender_sys;
   String destination_sys;
   **int current_time;**
   char message_type;

................

}
```

could anyone please suggest me how to do this using java?

Comment: SO is actually support search.

Comment: I wanted to send current time range of 8bytes and according to given specs.

Comment: you sure you want _nanoseconds_, not _milliseconds_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1_000_000L;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very much helpful

Answer (score 0):

I converted long value of current_time into bytes as below.

```
public static byte[] longToBytes(long current_time) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(Long.SIZE / 8);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeLong(current_time);
        byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
        dos.close();
        System.out.println(result.length);//length=8bytes
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
Duration               // Represent a span of time unattached to the time line.    
    .between(          // Calculate elapsed time.
        Instant.UTC ,  // Constant for 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
        Instant.now()  // Current moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
    )                  // Returns a `Duration` object.
    .toNanos()         // Returns a `long` integer.
```

## *java.time*

Use the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To get a count of the nanoseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z):

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Duration d = Duration.between( Instant.UTC , now ) ;
long nanos = d.toNanos() ;
```